# How to call a click command without the '--' and assign value to it without the '=' sign?

Tags: python, command-line-interface, python-click

```
@click.command()
@click.option("--hello", type=click.Path(exists=True))
def read_config(hello):
```

Trying to pass a file as the argument to the command declared above,

At present the command is executed the following way:
`python main.py --hello=filename.txt`

How do I change the working format of the above command to as follows:
`python main.py hello filename.txt`

I'm using the latest version of the click library, and I would like to know if there is a way to make the intended change using the same library.

New to the click library, I know how it can be done using Argparse, but click library is preferred.

Comment: builtin `argparse` may do everything you need https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html

Comment: That's not how command lines are intended to work. `python main.py hello filename.txt` does not mean that you want `filename.txt` to be the value of `hello`. It means that you are passing two **unnamed** values, and `hello` is the first one and `filename.txt` is the second. It's the same as in the code itself: `my_function('hello', 'filename.txt')` is fundamentally not going to mean the same thing as `my_function(hello='filename.txt')`, and if you want the former to do what the latter used to do, you are going to have to rewrite the function.

Answer (score 1):

Use a group to define `read_config` as a subcommand, then add an argument, not an option, to the subcommand.

```
@click.group()
def cli():
    """This doesn't really need to do anything."""


@cli.command()
@click.argument('filename', type=click.Path(exists=True))
def hello(filename):
    ...


if __name__ == '__main__':
    cli()
```

Comment: Hey Chepner, tried changing it into an argument, but that is not giving the desired result.

Comment: Ah, yes, I forgot about the "subcommand" `hello`.